# Memory leak when I add last a node to a doubly linked list C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

I am facing a memory leak when I add last a node to a doubly linked list.
My function is:

```
void addLast(const char* word){ // This is a homework and the parameter must be const char*
std::string c2 = word; // My nodes are std::string
Node *aux = new Node(c2);
if (tail == NULL) {
head = tail = aux; }

else {
tail->next = aux; aux->prev = tail; tail = aux; }
}
```

My strct Node is the following:

```
struct Node {
std::string value; Node *next, *prev;
Node (std::string value) {
this->value = value; next = prev = NULL; }
Node () {
next = prev = NULL; } }
```

I mention the fact that if I try to delete aux in function addLast I face a SEG FAULT. What is the problem>

Comment: The code looks OK to me. What makes you believe there's a memory leak, and that it's in this function?

Comment: Valgrind tells that is a memory leak at operator new[] in function addLast

Comment: Well, that means that you fail to eventually deallocate the node you've allocated here. So the problem is in the code that destroys the list.

Comment: We need the whole sample. It looks like you try to delete your tail twice. Without your create and delete code thats all just guessing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The following function is used by destructor:
void Clear() {
Node *p1 = head;
while (p1) {
Node *p2 = p1->next;
delete p1;
p1 = p2;
}
head = tail = NULL;}